Remove double quotes from COPY vertica command
I'm using Clickhouse S3 table engine to store data in csv file in S3 storage. This csv file from time to time is read by Vertica to consume data and paste into own table
DDL of clickhouse S3 table
  CREATE TABLE db.table on cluster 'cluster_name'
    (
        `id` String,
        `articles` UInt64,
        `app_days` UInt64,
        `search_count` UInt64,
        `city` String
    )
        ENGINE=S3('https://123.123.com/file.csv',
                  'key',
                  'secret_key',
                  'CSV')

When selecting table data on clickhouse side  'id' and 'city' columns do not have double quotes around its values but then when I copy data to vertica from csv I get double quotes around every value in these columns while selecting data from vertica table as example "111" or "NY"
Command I'm using to COPY data on vertica side:
   COPY db.table2(id, articles, app_day, search_count, city) 
    FROM 's3://file.csv'
    REJECTED DATA AS TABLE db.table2_rejected DELIMITER ','

How to to remove double quotes while copying data from CSV to vertica ?

Try to add ENCLOSED BY '"' after DELIMITER ','
